# Mover classe de um elemento para outro e habilitar janela para elemento selecionado usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como eu posso mover a classe para outro elemento que for clicado e remover a classe do anterior.

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div id="myDIV">
    <i class="active">1</i>
    <i>2</i>
    <i>3</i>
</div>
<div class="windows1">
...
</div>
<div class="windows2">
...
</div>
<div class="windows3">
...
</div>
```

O que preciso fazer é mover a classe **active** para o elemento clicado no caso são eles **1, 2 e 3**.

E preciso habilitar a div **window** conforme o elemento **1, 2 e 3** habilitado.

Answer (score -1):

Dentro da função executada através do atributo `onClick` do novo elemento capture os elementos que possuem a classe que você quer remover e em seguida adicione a classe ao elemento clicado.

Sugestão de código:

```
function removeClass(event) {
  const elementoNovo = event.target;
  const elementoAntigo = document.querySeletor('.nomeDaClaase');
  if (elementoAntigo === null) {
   elementoNovo.classList.add('nomeDaClasse');
  } else {
   elementoAntigo.classList.remove('nomeDaClasse');
   elementoNovo.classList.add('nomeDaClasse');
  };
}
```

Dessa forma a função vai adicionar a classe que você quer ao elemento clicado removendo do elemento anterior.

O `if` evita que o código quebre na primeira execução caso o valor de `elementoAntigo` seja igual a `NULL`, logo se for a primeira vez que a função executa, a funçaõ simplesmente adicionará a classe desejada ao elemento clicado.

Você pode colocar a chamada dessa função no atributo `onClick` do elemento HTML da seguinte forma: `onClick={ (event) => removeClass(event) }`.

Documentação sobre [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Documentação sobre [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Documentação sobre a [captura de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).